# ElasticSeach RequestError in a Flask app: query works fine with only one of two models (search_phase_execution_exception, failed to create query)

Tags: python, elasticsearch, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I keep getting this error when I try to use ElasticSearch to query one index, but not another:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'failed to 
create query: {\n  "multi_match" : {\n    "query" : "bob",\n    "fields" : [\n      
"additional_comments^1.0",\n      "age^1.0",\n      "first_name^1.0",\n      "gender^1.0",\n      
"needs^1.0",\n      "program_number^1.0",\n      "read^1.0",\n      "sheet_size^1.0",\n      
"shoe_size_category^1.0",\n      "shoe_sock_size^1.0",\n      "shoe_type^1.0",\n      
"time_chosen^1.0",\n      "wants^1.0",\n      "wear^1.0"\n    ],\n    "type" : "best_fields",\n    
"operator" : "OR",\n    "slop" : 0,\n    "fuzziness" : "50",\n    "prefix_length" : 0,\n    
"max_expansions" : 50,\n    "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",\n    "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : 
true,\n    "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,\n    "boost" : 1.0\n  }\n}')
```

I have the following ES query:

```
def query_object(index, fields, query, page, per_page, fuzziness=0):
    print(index)
    print(query)
    print(fields)
    search = current_app.elasticsearch.search(
        index=index,
        body={'query': {'multi_match': {'query': query, 'fields': fields, 'fuzziness': fuzziness}},
              'from': (page - 1) * per_page, 'size': per_page}
    )

    ids = [int(hit['_id']) for hit in search['hits']['hits']]
    return ids, search['hits']['total']['value']
```

Here's the class method for searches, which is a parent for both searchable classes:

```
class SearchableMixin(object):
    @classmethod
    def search_object(cls, fields, expression, page, per_page, fuzziness=0):
        ids, total = query_object(
            cls.__tablename__, fields, expression, page, per_page, fuzziness=fuzziness)
        if total == 0:
            return cls.query.filter_by(id=0), 0
        when = []
        for i in range(len(ids)):
            when.append((ids[i], i))
        return cls.query.filter(cls.id.in_(ids)).order_by(
            db.case(when, value=cls.id)), total
```

Here is the User class:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin, SearchableMixin):
    __searchable__ = ['email', 'phone', 'street_address',
                      'city', 'state', 'zip_code', 'last_reminded']
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=True, default=None)
    password = db.Column(db.String(200))
    street_address = db.Column(db.String(100))
    city = db.Column(db.String(100))
    state = db.Column(db.String(52))
    zip_code = db.Column(db.String(10))
    last_reminded = db.Column(db.String(40), default=datetime.utcnow().strftime(
        "%A, %B %e{}, %Y".format(suffix(datetime.today().day))))
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    wish_lists = db.relationship('WishList', backref='sponsor', lazy='dynamic')
    drives = db.relationship(
        'HolidayCheerDrive', secondary=years, lazy='dynamic')
```

And here is the WishList class:

```
class WishList(db.Model, SearchableMixin):
    __searchable__ = ['program_number', 'first_name', 'age', 'gender', 'wants', 'needs', 'wear',
    'read', 'shoe_sock_size', 'shoe_size_category', 'shoe_type', 'sheet_size', 'additional_comments', 'time_chosen',
                      ]
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    program_number = db.Column(db.String(4))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(20))
    age = db.Column(db.String(10))
    gender = db.Column(db.String(20))
    wants = db.Column(db.String(300))
    needs = db.Column(db.String(300))
    wear = db.Column(db.String(300))
    read = db.Column(db.String(300))
    pant_dress_size = db.Column(db.String(20), default='unspecified')
    shirt_blouse_size = db.Column(db.String(20), default='unspecified')
    jacket_sweater_size = db.Column(db.String(20), default='unspecified')
    shoe_sock_size = db.Column(db.String(20), default='unspecified')
    shoe_size_category = db.Column(db.String(20), default='unspecified')
    shoe_type = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=True, default=None)
    sheet_size = db.Column(db.String(20))
    additional_comments = db.Column(db.Text(), nullable=True, default=None)
    time_chosen = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=True, default=None)
    sponsor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
        'user.id'), nullable=True, default=None)
    drive_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
        'holiday_cheer_drive.id'), nullable=False, default=None)
```

I tried taking out the `time_chosen` searchable term because it isn't defined yet, but that didn't help. I also tried only searching a single field, and that didn't work either. When I search User, it doesn't return any errors. The python routes don't seem to have any errors as far as I can tell, here they are:

```
@bp.route('/manage_users', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
#@admin_only
def manage_users():
    form = SearchUsersForm()
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    if not form.validate():
        all_users = User.query.all()
        total = len(all_users)
        start = ((page-1) * current_app.config['RESULTS_PER_PAGE'])
        end = (start + current_app.config['RESULTS_PER_PAGE'])
        if end >= total:
            display_users = all_users[start:]
        else:
            display_users = all_users[start:end]
    else:
        if form.fields.data == 'default':
            fields = [field for field in User.__searchable__]
        elif form.fields.data == 'address':
            fields = ['street_address', 'city', 'state', 'zip_code']
        else:
            fields = [form.fields.data]

        fuzzy = True
        if fuzzy:
            fuzziness = 50
        else:
            fuzziness = 0

        display_users, total = User.search_object(fields, form.q.data, page,
                                                  current_app.config['RESULTS_PER_PAGE'], fuzziness=fuzziness)

    q = form.q.data if form.q.data else None
    next_url = url_for('admin.manage_users', q=q, page=page + 1) \
        if total > page * current_app.config['RESULTS_PER_PAGE'] else None
    prev_url = url_for('admin.manage_users', q=q, page=page - 1) \
        if page > 1 else None
    context = {
        'next_url': next_url,
        'prev_url': prev_url,
        'display_users': display_users,
        'form': form,
    }
    return render_template('/admin/manage_users.html', **context)


@bp.route('/manage_wish_lists', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
#@admin_only
def manage_wish_lists():
    form = SearchWishListsForm()
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    if not form.validate():
        all_wish_lists = WishList.query.all()
        total = len(all_wish_lists)
        start = ((page-1) * current_app.config['RESULTS_PER_PAGE'])
        end = (start + current_app.config['RESULTS_PER_PAGE'])
        if end >= total:
            display_lists = all_wish_lists[start:]
        else:
            display_lists = all_wish_lists[start:end]
    else:
        if form.fields.data == 'default':
            fields = [field for field in WishList.__searchable__]
        elif form.fields.data == 'wish_list_items':
            fields = ['wants', 'need', 'wear', 'read']
        elif form.fields.data == "shoes":
            fields = ['shoe_sock_size', 'shoe_size_category', 'shoe_type']
        else:
            fields = [form.fields.data]

        fuzzy = True
        if fuzzy:
            fuzziness = 50
        else:
            fuzziness = 0

        display_lists, total = WishList.search_object(fields, form.q.data, page,
                                                      current_app.config['RESULTS_PER_PAGE'], fuzziness=fuzziness)

    q = form.q.data if form.q.data else None
    next_url = url_for('admin.manage_wish_lists', q=q, page=page + 1) \
        if total > page * current_app.config['RESULTS_PER_PAGE'] else None
    prev_url = url_for('admin.manage_wish_lists', q=q, page=page - 1) \
        if page > 1 else None
    context = {
        'next_url': next_url,
        'prev_url': prev_url,
        'display_lists': display_lists,
        'form': form,
    }
    return render_template('/admin/manage_wish_lists.html', **context)
```

I don't get it. I am querying a very similar object with the same query, and everything--including the index and queries--are printing correctly to the terminal.

in the search function I add:

```
    print(index)
    print(query)
    print(fields)
    import json
    body={'query': {'multi_match': {'query': query, 'fields': fields, 'fuzziness': fuzziness}},
              'from': (page - 1) * per_page, 'size': per_page}
    print(json.dumps(body))
    search = current_app.elasticsearch.search(
        index=index,
        body={'query': {'multi_match': {'query': query, 'fields': fields, 'fuzziness': fuzziness}},
              'from': (page - 1) * per_page, 'size': per_page}
    )
    print(json.dumps(search))
```

**Edited output for these `print` statements**

For the User object:

```
#INDEX NAME
user
#QUERY TERMS
bob
#SEARCH FIELDS
['email', 'phone', 'street_address', 'city', 'state', 'zip_code', 'last_reminded']
#BODY OF SEARCH
{"query": {"multi_match": {"query": "bob", "fields": ["email", "phone", "street_address", "city", "state", "zip_code", "last_reminded"], "fuzziness": 50}}, "from": 0, "size": 10}
#SEARCH JSON
{"took": 18, "timed_out": false, "_shards": {"total": 1, "successful": 1, "skipped": 0, "failed": 0}, "hits": {"total": {"value": 0, "relation": "eq"}, "max_score": null, "hits": []}}
```

For the WishList object:

```
#INDEX NAME
wish_list
#QUERY TERMS
bob
#SEARCH FIELDS
['program_number', 'first_name', 'age', 'gender', 'wants', 'needs', 'wear', 'read', 'shoe_sock_size', 'shoe_size_category', 'shoe_type', 'sheet_size', 'additional_comments', 'time_chosen']
#BODY OF SEARCH
{"query": {"multi_match": {"query": "bob", "fields": ["program_number", "first_name", "age", "gender", "wants", "needs", "wear", "read", "shoe_sock_size", "shoe_size_category", "shoe_type", "sheet_size", "additional_comments", "time_chosen"], "fuzziness": 50}}, "from": 0, "size": 10}
#Cannot build query so search object never instantiates
```

Only difference is, the User object does not give me an error and returns a search result that I can see on my HTML page. The WishList object when queries throws the error I pasted above.

Please let me know... is there something wrong with my routes? Is it possible to index too many fields? `additional_comments` is a text column instead of a string column; is it possible that this could play a role?

I'm at a loss. Help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

**Edits: I'm adding the output to my ElasticSearch server terminal below in case that is helpful. This JSON may be oragnized better, visually speaking?**

```
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) ~[?:?]
[2020-03-23T09:34:43,437][DEBUG][o.e.a.s.TransportSearchAction] [LAPTOP-G8TTIC4C] All shards failed for phase: [query]
org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryShardException: failed to create query: {
  "multi_match" : {
    "query" : "bob",
    "fields" : [
      "additional_comments^1.0",
      "age^1.0",
      "first_name^1.0",
      "gender^1.0",
      "needs^1.0",
      "program_number^1.0",
      "read^1.0",
      "sheet_size^1.0",
      "shoe_size_category^1.0",
      "shoe_sock_size^1.0",
      "shoe_type^1.0",
      "time_chosen^1.0",
      "wants^1.0",
      "wear^1.0"
    ],
    "type" : "best_fields",
    "operator" : "OR",
    "slop" : 0,
    "fuzziness" : "50",
    "prefix_length" : 0,
    "max_expansions" : 50,
    "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
    "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
    "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
        at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryShardContext.toQuery(QueryShardContext.java:350) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryShardContext.toQuery(QueryShardContext.java:333) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:750) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:591) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:550) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:351) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.lambda$executeQueryPhase$1(SearchService.java:343) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener.lambda$map$2(ActionListener.java:146) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$1.onResponse(ActionListener.java:63) [elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRunnable.lambda$supply$0(ActionRunnable.java:58) [elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRunnable$2.doRun(ActionRunnable.java:73) [elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) [elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.TimedRunnable.doRun(TimedRunnable.java:44) [elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:692) [elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) [elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only use fuzzy queries on keyword and text fields - not on [shoe_sock_size] which is of type [long]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MappedFieldType.fuzzyQuery(MappedFieldType.java:356) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.search.MatchQuery$MatchQueryBuilder.lambda$newTermQuery$0(MatchQuery.java:569) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.search.MatchQuery$MatchQueryBuilder.newTermQuery(MatchQuery.java:579) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.search.MatchQuery.parse(MatchQuery.java:277) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.search.MultiMatchQuery.buildFieldQueries(MultiMatchQuery.java:108) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.search.MultiMatchQuery.parse(MultiMatchQuery.java:76) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.query.MultiMatchQueryBuilder.doToQuery(MultiMatchQueryBuilder.java:833) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.query.AbstractQueryBuilder.toQuery(AbstractQueryBuilder.java:99) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryShardContext.lambda$toQuery$1(QueryShardContext.java:334) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryShardContext.toQuery(QueryShardContext.java:346) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        ... 17 more
```

Comment: can you share your search query in JSON format

Comment: Ah, OK, yes--sorry, I'm at my work computer. If you were able to give me a quick instruction on how to do that, it would make it easier for in a bit when I'm back :-D

Comment: I am not sure about flask and how to get the search JSON in your case, just see if you can get all the details like search JSON, JSON mapping etc , as this would help me to troubleshoot your issue, ES works very well with REST apis in JSON format

Comment: OK! Thank you! I'll get on that as soon as I'm off shift.

Comment: @OpsterElasticSearchNinja Hi -- I got out late and went to sleep. I am about to add edits with JSON formatted data. Thanks again!

Comment: sure no issues :), just keep only the JSON data and ES has a very good support for REST APIs and Its better to first solve it using API, then you can ask programming specific another question, if you follow Elasticsearch questions thisis the normal pattern and chances of you getting answer will increase a lot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210176/discussion-between-peter-charland-and-opster-elasticsearch-ninja).

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja Hey, I figured it out. Thanks for the help. I am now going to search for a solution to the problem I described in my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that when I set the data types of the search fields explicitly to 'text', the query builds fine in all cases where I don't search the numeric-like fields. Before, all fields were not building correctly.

I have set the index class function in the `SearchableMixin` class to the following:

```
def add_to_index(index, model):
    payload = {}
    properties = {}
    for field in model.__searchable__:
        payload[field] = getattr(model, field)
        properties[field] = {'type': 'text'}
    payload['mappings'] = {'properties': properties}
    current_app.elasticsearch.index(index=index, id=model.id, body=payload)
```

I am now able to query both classes, but like I said, just not within the numeric-like fields (`program_number`, `shoe_sock_size`, and `age` are all integers or floats coerced to string). I'll research or ask another question to work on that problem.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: basically your `program_number` , `age` stores just numbers but stores as strings in ES and you are not able to search on them ?

Comment: Yes, exactly! :)

Comment: Again I can show how to do it using RESt API is it fine for your?

Comment: OK, that would be good--I guess I'll have to take that and figure out how to get the python package to do it. Thanks a ton man! :)

Comment: Hey @OpsterElasticsearchNinja -- I don't know if you got my repsonse, but if you can show me how to do it using the elasticsearch REST API that would still be very welcome assistance!!

Comment: for some reason I am not able to tag you :(, yeah I can do that, but this question isn't the right place for it, as it would not be helpful for the community and as an experienced community member, it's my responsibilities to maintain the sanity of the platform. can you ask a new question, good news I just prepared a sample to answer your question :),  just comment  the question link here as soon as you ask

Comment: are you writing a new question, as I am about to go to bed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60860090/how-do-i-tell-an-elasticsearch-multi-match-query-that-i-want-numeric-fields-sto

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210347/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-peter-charland).